# What does "as they do" mean in this Nobel citation?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> He was an American writer and the 1962 Nobel Prize in Literature winner *"for his realistic and imaginative writings, combining **as they do** sympathetic humor and keen social perception."* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1962_Nobel_Prize_in_Literature))

I don't understand the clause "combining *as they do* sympathetic humor and keen social perception".

Comment: It is equivalent to *which they do.* It has been fronted so that it refers cataphorically. You can read it as "combining sympathetic humor and keen social perception, which they do."

Comment: (For anyone curious but unable to Google it, the author in question is John Steinbeck.)

Answer (score 8):

***-ING VERB + AS + PRONOUN + DO/DOES*** is often used in academic, formal writing as a language device ***to add confirmation, emphasis or simply stylistic effect***. It is a type of ***[parenthesis](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-parenthetical-element-1857161)***, although it is not always separated by commas from the rest of the text. As such, it can be dropped without loss of meaning.

CAGEL classifies it as a *comparative clause*, giving this example (with ***it*** as a subject):

> The deadlock is a disappointment coming ***[as it does]*** after such a promising start.

Commenting on it, the authors note:

> The matrix <sub>*(that is whatever is outside the brackets)*</sub> does not state that the proposition is
> true, whereas *the comparative clause does*. The latter does therefore ***introduce a new feature, but it is not a matter of the lexical content***. (p. 1149)

That part of the sentence you are asking about means:

> ... for his writings, combining *as they do* ***[as we can observe they do** or **as indeed they do]*** sympathetic humor and keen social perception.

So in a way, it does confirm the truth of the action expressed by the gerund preceding the phrase *as they do*.

Here are some instances I have found in books:

> - As did the person from whom I first heard it, who assured me similar formulations will soon be an essential element of the Queen's English – ***combining as they do*** an obvious prefix with the syllable I have been given to understand... (*Fiendish Schemes*, K. W. Jeter, 2017)
> - If maps are indeed unique as redoubled representations of earthscapes — ***combining as they do*** presentational with discursive symbolism — this uniqueness is especially evident... (*Representing Place: Landscape Painting and Maps*, Edward S. Casey · 2002)

Note that the expression can follow any other participle, and ***it*** and ***they*** are the most common subjects of do/does:

> - In its universal function, it may represent an ultimate term, but it is by no means an ultimate truth or entity, ***marking as it does*** the functionality of the representative system as such through its open character. (*Lacan and Cassirer: An Essay on Symbolisation*, Antoine Mooij · 2018)
> - ... its presence in the archive is noteworthy, ***indicating as it does*** the length of time over which charters could survive in lay hands... (*Anglo-Saxon Glastonbury: Church and Endowment*, Lesley Abrams · 1996)

Answer (score 6):

@fev has explained the general usage of “as they do”, from which the answer to the question “what does (it) mean in this Nobel citation” can be seen to be:

> **Nothing**

It is completely redundant and nothing is lost by omitting it to read:

> "for his realistic and imaginative writings, combining sympathetic humor and keen social perception."

Comment: I am not sure it is redundant here. *As* can mean *in the way that*; the citation can be read as emphasizing not the mere fact that the writings combine "sympathetic humor and keen social perception", but that they do so in some particular way (which is not elaborated here). Compare "I was surprised to see her dancing as she did", implying that it was a specific manner of dancing that prompted my surprise, a meaning not present if "as she did" were omitted.

Comment: @nanoman That's a different use of the phrase though.  That is the difference between "combining as they do x and y" and "combining x and y as they do".  The former just means that they're combined.  The latter means they're combined in some particular way that is important.

Comment: @nanoman — If that were the intent, it would have been better to write “and the way they combine” instead. As it is, one suspects it suffers from “writing by committee” — in this case one composed mainly of non-native English speakers, with the native speakers too polite to criticize (or perhaps vice versa).

Comment: @nasch I'm not sure of that distinction -- how does it work if, in place of "combining", the sentence uses an *intransitive* verb like my "dancing"? Then there is no object like "x and y" whose position relative to "as they do" could make your claimed distinction. In other words, how could I phrase *my* sentence with "as she did" in a way that conveys the mere fact of dancing, as you claim "combining as they do x and y" conveys the mere fact of combining?

Comment: @nanoman "I was surprised to see her, as she was, dancing." A bit awkward but that expresses that you were surprised to see that she was dancing, rather than that you were surprised to see the manner in which she was dancing.